# Pull data from text file into a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, text-files

I'm currently having problem trying to pull data from a textfile using a struct and then storing it into a vector. But no matter wad I do, unless i change the values of float,int to strings, it will always give me errors like this:

> MissionPlan.cpp:190: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’
>   MissionPlan.cpp:190: error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘size_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)

This is my struct:

```
struct CivIndexDB {
float civInd;
int x;
int y;
}
```

This is my example text file:

> 3.2341:2:3
>   1.5234:3:4

This is the code that I use to extract the data from the textfile and then storing it into a vector:

```
string line = "";
while (getline(civIndexFile,line)) {
    stringstream linestream(line);

    getline(linestream,civDb.civInd,':');
    getline(linestream,civDb.x,':');
    getline(linestream,civDb.y);
    civIndexesList.push_back(civDb);            
}
```

Changing the variable types in the struct to string is not what I need as later in the application, I need to sort the vector values based on its float value.

I appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use binary files? i don't remember how to write binary file but i think in your example they are more appropriate.

Comment: You can always read into a string, and then convert the string into the number you need in your struct. But I think P0W's answer is the simplest.

Comment: @john if the struct variables are of string type, then the data stored into the vector has to be string type. Even if i convert the string in to the type that i need, I would still need a vector capable of storing float,int,int (which i think is pretty impossible) and sort it out later.

Comment: @JoelSeah I didn't say that the struct variables should be strings. I meant that you can read into a *local* string variable and the convert the local variable to a number when you place that number in your struct. `string s; getline(linestream,s,':'); civDb.civInd=convertStringToFloat(s);`. Of course you still have to write the convertStringToFloat function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking into your exact problem/errors, I suggest, if the file format is fixed simplest way would be :

```
char ch; // For ':'
while (civIndexFile >> civDb.civInd >> ch >> civDb.x >> ch >> civDb.y )
{
    civIndexesList.push_back(civDb); 
}
```

**Edit**

For sorting on float values you can overload `<` operator :

```
struct CivIndexDB {
  float civInd;
  int x;
  int y;

  bool operator <(const CivIndexDB& db) const
  {
    return db.civInd > civInd;
  }
};
```

And then use `std::sort` :

`std::sort(civIndexesList.begin(), civIndexesList.end() );`

Comment: Seems like changing the file format is the best bet that I have right now. But could you tell me the difference between binary and text-mode files? I read the online sources and I don't really understand them.

Comment: @JoelSeah why are you changing file format, `float:int:int` will work perfectly with above code. Try [this](http://pastebin.com/6vhiVH6U) code, change the filename

Comment: didn't you ask me to change the file from text to binary and then using the above code to test it out?

Comment: @JoelSeah no I didn't I just said, if its exactly what you posted then the simplest approach will be the above code

Comment: thanks. i always thought that the only way to get data from a textfile is to use `stringstream`. If i'm not wrong, the reason why the struct variables only work as string is bcoz of the `stringstream`. is it?

Comment: is there a limit to the number of values the program can read from the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct CivIndexDB {
    float civInd;
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream civIndexFile;
    std::string filename = "data.dat";

    civIndexFile.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);

    std::vector<CivIndexDB> civ;
    CivIndexDB cid;

    if (civIndexFile.is_open()) {
        std::string temp;

        while(std::getline(civIndexFile, temp)) {
            std::istringstream iss(temp);
            int param = 0;
            int x=0, y=0;
            float id = 0;

            while(std::getline(iss, temp, ':')) {
                std::istringstream ist(temp);
                if (param == 0) {
                    (ist >> id) ? cid.civInd = id : cid.civInd = 0;
                }
                else if (param == 1) {
                    (ist >> x) ? cid.x = x : cid.x = 0;
                }
                else if (param == 2) {
                    (ist >> y) ? cid.y = y : cid.y = 0;
                }
                ++param;
            }
            civ.push_back(cid);
        }
    }   
    else {
        std::cerr << "There was a problem opening the file!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < civ.size(); ++i) {
        cid = civ[i];
        std::cout << cid.civInd << " " << cid.x << " " << cid.y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```